# How do I unlock 200cc mode?

Tags: mario-kart-8

So I downloaded the update (4.0 shows on the title screen) but there is no 200cc option when I go to choose a race. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the 4.1 patch, 200cc mode is automatically unlocked in all modes, including Grand Prix, so the solution is to update from 4.0.

Comment: I have the new update (4.0), but no option for 200cc. Do I need to have stars in all 150cc races or something?

Comment: @Mathias711 You need gold trophies (first place) on all 150cc races. No stars necessary. Easier to just upgrade to 4.1, if possible.

Comment: Is it unlocked in 4.1, regardless of previous trophies?

Comment: @Mathias711 Yep